# How to solve a exponential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to get an expression for $a$ but am not able too...

- $0 < \theta < 1 $
- $1 + (1/a)$ = $((2/a) + 1)^\theta$

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no neat expression for that. To be honest, you are not looking for a number; you are looking for a *function*, the inverse function of
$$\theta = \frac{\ln(a+1)-\ln(a)}{\ln(a+2) - \ln(a)} $$
This is quite ugly. Let's come back to the original expression, and imagine that $a$ is a $C^{\infty} $ function of $\theta$: deriving the expression two times in the right way (I don't report passages) gets you rid of logarithms, and you obtain

$$a' [\theta (a+1)^2 - 2(a+2)(a+1)^2-(a+2)^2] +a'' [(a+1)(a+2)^2- \theta (a+1)^2(a+2)] = 0$$

And this is a clearly ugly problem equivalent to your question. But if you numerically need the answer, try with newton method. Given $\theta_0$, you are searching a zero of the function

$$f(a) =\ln( 1+\frac{1}{a}) - \theta_0 \ln( 1+\frac{2}{a})$$

Making a few calculations yield the following method: start with $a_0=$. Then calculate
$$ a_{n+1}= a_n - \frac{(\ln(1+\frac{1}{a_n}) - \theta_0 \ln(1+\frac{2}{a_n}) )(a_n+2)(a_n+1)} {a_n( a_n(1-\theta_0) + 2- \theta_0)} $$

This converges to the solution. 
Hope it helps, Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Set $x=1+1/a$, then the equation is $x=(2x-1)^θ$ or $x^{1/θ}=2x-1$. Even if $1/θ$ is an integer, if that integer is larger than $4$ then there is no expression for the solution, as is known by Galois theory for polynomials of degree $5$ and higher.

Comment: This holds for a general polynomial! But who knows if the galois group of, say, $f(x) =x^5-2x-1$ is solvable or not? If, foe example, we find two primes p, q such that gal(f mod p) contains a 5 cycle, gal(f mod q) contains a 2-cycle,by a general theorem gal(f over Q) contains a 2-cycle and a 5-cycle, thus it is S_5 which is not solvable. We are close, you had a good intuition!

Comment: Actually, it has 1 as a root, so it has degree 4. We must choose a greater theta, and try some reductions.